# Tracking manual points with KLT

Tags: c++, video-tracking

I'm having trouble successfully tracking a user-selected feature point using the KLT tracking algorithm and header files. I'm programming in C++ VS Express 2010, and am trying to do this without OpenCV or other libraries. Here are the steps I'm taking to track each point at a time:

1. Make a tracking context
2. Make a feature list
3. Adjust feature list count (to one), set x and y position
4. Fill two image data containers
5. Call KLTTrackFeatures() with appropriate arguments
6. Take new x and y values from feature list, and insert back into custom data structure

That's pretty much it. I've fiddled with some attributes like borders etc to no avail. The results I get can vary from coords marked as -1, to positions where the point shouldn't be. I've found it difficult searching for this one, because most searches result in OpenCV related topics which don't seem to deal directly with klt itself. Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on how to go about solving this?

Kind regards,

OJnr.

Comment: [tag:c++] or [tag:c]? Pick one..

Comment: The klt header files are c, but my program is being developed in c++. Should I remove the c tag?

Comment: Yes, you should. You need a [tag:c++] solution for your [tag:c++] code.

Comment: No worries - tag removed, cheers.